# Could Not Find error when deleting files

Tags: windows-10, ghost

I have what appear to be "ghost files" that I cannot delete. I tried the command window and did del then files name. Could Not Find D:\Export\0001. Any thoughts? this is driving me crazy.
I am on Windows 10.

Answer (score 0):

Most cases due to filename got space or dot at the end.

You can try to delete using command line as below example I got from this credit site:

del “\?\C:\Temp\YourFile.txt.” or “del “\?\C:\Temp\File.txt “

Most of the time, the solution fit the problem.

Credit: https://geekzag.com/guides/computers/could-not-find-this-item/